# How do I add a popup menu view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to implement a feature in my app that is similar to Apple's weather app. Here is a photo example:

[image]

From the looks of it, it is a button and when the user clicks on it, something else appears. What kind of SwiftUI control is that? Basically, what code made that button and resulting little (mini) menu that appears?

Answer (score 7):

That would be the `menu`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct menuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack{
                    Text("this is a test")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My custom title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Create a file", systemImage: "doc")
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Create a folder", systemImage: "folder")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That would be a `Menu`.

As per the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu), here is an example of usage:

```swift
Menu("Actions") {
    Button("Duplicate", action: duplicate)
    Button("Rename", action: rename)
    Button("Delete…", action: delete)
    Menu("Copy") {
        Button("Copy", action: copy)
        Button("Copy Formatted", action: copyFormatted)
        Button("Copy Library Path", action: copyPath)
    }
}
```

If you want the button to open the menu to be an SF Symbol, like the ellipse with the three dots, you can call `Menu` a bit differently:

```swift
Menu {
     // Add options here...
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
}
```